# Nodes created in crxde lite disappear upon reload

Tags: aem, aem-6

I'm attempting to create a node within the CRXDE lite interface (I understand that this could be done in other IDE's) But for some reason after creating everything I need, it is all deleted upon a reload.

Here is the path I took

1. Opened http://localhost:4502/crx/de
2. Right clicked on /apps/wknd/components/structure and chose 'create node'

[image]

3. Followed the steps here https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-wknd-tutorial-develop/pages-templates.html creating the nodes and specifying the jcr parameters
   [image]
4. Clicked Save All
5. In terminal went to ui.apps and used the command

   mvn -PautoInstallPackage -Padobe-public clean install

   (I've performed the above with and without step 5 with the same result)
6. Then I either click the refresh button or refresh the page.
   [image]

Performing all these steps the nodes I created disappear. Here are some possible clues I noticed.

- It immediately disappears when performing step 5.
- When saving in crxde it doesn't seem to actually make any files in the file system (at least not in the project I can see)

I've researched the steps involving node creation on this page https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/developing-with-crxde-lite.html#CreatingaNode but it doesn't seem to say I need to do anything other than click Save All. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is using an IDE(Eclipse) to create the nodes or pages which automatically pushes the changes to your AEM environment(server has to be configured)

It seems you are making the changes in the AEM CRX/de console, Once you executed step 5, it will override all the manual changes made in the server (It will push the changes from your local directory).

You can use this below tutorials to set up your IDE as used in the documentation

> https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-learn/foundation/development/set-up-a-local-aem-development-environment.html#setup-integrated-env

About your concern on not using IDE, if you would like to make the changes directly in **CRX/DE**, there are a couple of options to get it work.

1. Create a package of your changes in package manager and copy the changes to your local repository and then do a build
2. You can also use vault commands to pull in the content from an IDE

> **Step by Step Procedure to Create a package** (Attached screenshot as references for the steps)
>
> 1. Navigate to Package Manager http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp
> 2. Click on Create Package (https://www.screencast.com/t/yW9BYcCyT)
> 3. Enter Package name and group (Can be anything) and click OK (https://www.screencast.com/t/HmRkm7qY)
> 4. Edit the package (https://www.screencast.com/t/i00J559Hf1tc)
> 5. Navigate to filters Tab and Click on Add Filter (https://www.screencast.com/t/0MugoSEdHT)
> 6. Enter the path to export, in your case it will be **/apps/wknd/components/structure**
> 7. Click Done and Click on Save
> 8. Click on Build and then download the package. (https://www.screencast.com/t/no0oEv7ShMi)
> 9. Extract the zip file and copy the /apps/wknd/components/structure folder to your local code repository and do a build

Answer (score 1):

Step 5 is deploying your project to your local AEM instance and installing it. This means that all your changes on that path will be overwritten. Works as designed!

Answer (score 1):

CRXDE is handy to create a base structure, but make sure you backup these changes by adding them to your local code. You can create a package, unzip and  copy the required files. Then on your next build you will have them, otherwise, they will be overwritten.

Also, review the filter rules (`filter.xml`), in case you add a new path and then include it in your package that is built via the maven command.